# PHP e Mysql Divisão sem resto em PHP divisão de tarefas

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, divisão

Galera é o seguinte preciso atribuir tarefas a um numero variável de participantes.
EX: Através de um select obtive 49 tarefas a ser executadas e tenho que distribuir para 4 funcionários. Ou seja a divisão seria assim **1º funcionário**  teria 12 tarefas o **2º funcionário**  teria 12 tarefas o  **3º funcionário**  teria 12 tarefas e o 4º funcionário  teria 13 tarefas que seria o restante. 
Tanto a quantidade de  tarefas quantos os funcionários vem de um select podem variar e cada tarefa e funcionário tem um código único.
Funcionário 1 tarefa 1
Funcionário 1 tarefa 2
e assim ate completar 12 dai passaria para o outro com mais 12...

Estou usando PHP PDO Mysql e preciso  fazer um loop que faça esta distribuição da forma que expliquei mas não sei como fazer. se algum puder me ajudar ficarei muito agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo,

Fiz aqui, mas não pude compilar. Acredito ser o suficiente para você enterder a lógica que apliquei... espero que te ajude!

```
<?php

  $qtdTarefas = 49;
  $qtdFuncionarios = 4;
  $aux = 0;

  while($qtdTarefas != 0){ //Enquanto existir tarefa...
    $funcionario[$aux] = recebeTarefa(); //Funcionario recebe a tarefa
    if(($qtdTarefas - 2) < 0){//Se essa for a penultima tarela da lista
      $qtdTarefas--;
      $funcionario[$aux] = recebeTarefa();//O mesmo funcionario recebe essa outra tarefa
      break;//Para o loop
    } else {
      $qtdTarefas--;
      $aux++;
      if ($aux > $qtdFuncionarios){ //Volta ao funcionario 0 quando chega no ultimo
        $aux = 0;
      }
    }
  }

 ?>
```

Abraços